# how to get current value from input field in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to get current value from input field, but after onclick I am getting preious value in colsole.
here is my code

```
    import { React, useState } from "react";

const CompoundIntrest = () => {
  const [capitalValue, setcapitalValue] = useState(1000);
  const ChangeCapital = () => {
    setcapitalValue(capitalValue - 100);
  };
  const Calculate = () => {
    console.log(capitalValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          ChangeCapital();
          Calculate();
        }}
      >
        click
      </button>
      <input type="number" value={capitalValue} />
    </>
  );
};

export default CompoundIntrest;
```

Comment: You can use SSM's solution to access the new value before the the new render,  or Paras' solution to access the new value after the new render

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should add onChange method in input tag like below:

Then you get current value in onClick event in button tag.

```js
import { React, useState } from "react";

const CompoundIntrest = () => {
  const [capitalValue, setcapitalValue] = useState(1000);
  const ChangeCapital = () => {
    setcapitalValue(capitalValue - 100);
  };
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const Calculate = () => {
      console.log(capitalValue);
    };
    Calculate()
  }, [capitalValue])
  

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          ChangeCapital();
        }}
      >
        click
      </button>
      <input type="number" value={capitalValue} onChange={(e) => setcapitalValue(e.target.value)} />
    </>
  );
};

export default CompoundIntrest;
```

Comment: This does not work, i have to get current value after onclick

Comment: I think you are trying to say, we didn't get currentValue in console right ? for that i changed my answer please check it

Answer (score 1):

State updates occur asynchronously, so you won't have the updated state value inside the event handler.

You can lift the new value i.e. `capitalValue - 100` to a scope from where it can be passed down to both `ChangeCapital` & `Calculate`.

```js
const CompoundIntrest = () => {
  const [capitalValue, setCapitalValue] = React.useState(1000);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const newCapitalValue = capitalValue - 100;
    ChangeCapital(newCapitalValue);
    Calculate(newCapitalValue);
  };
  const ChangeCapital = (capitalValue) => {
    setCapitalValue(capitalValue);
  };
  const Calculate = (capitalValue) => {
    console.log(capitalValue);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>click</button>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={capitalValue}
        onChange={(e) => setCapitalValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<CompoundIntrest />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Note:** The state updater function is called synchronously but the state updates happen asynchronously.

This becomes more clear if you update the state by passing a state updater callback, you would see that the callback is fired synchronously. Notice the order of logs in the example below:

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("Before calling setCount");
    setCount((currCount) => {
      console.log("Inside setCount");
      return currCount + 1;
    });
    console.log("After calling setCount");
  };

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>Count: {count}</button>;
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Use useEffect Like this:-**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";

const CompoundIntrest  = () => {
  const [capitalValue, setcapitalValue] = useState(1000);
  const ChangeCapital = () => {
    setcapitalValue(capitalValue - 100);
  };
  const Calculate = () => {
    console.log(capitalValue);
  };
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log("afet chage",capitalValue);
  },[capitalValue]);
  return (
    <>
    <button
        onClick={() => {
          ChangeCapital();
          Calculate();
        }}
      >
        click
      </button>
      <input type="number" value={capitalValue} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onChange event in the input field to get current value.

```js
const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState['']

const changeHandler = (e:any) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { value } = e.target
  console.log('value', value);
  setCurrentValue(value)
}
```

```html
<input type="string" value={currentValue} onChange={(e:any) => changeHandler(e)}/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), other members have already provided the answer, I just want to give you an idea about [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).

Assuming that we are dealing with an uncontrolled component ( "input" element ) then how we can get the value.

```
    1. import { React, useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
    2. 
    3. const CompoundIntrest = () => {
    4. const [capitalValue, setcapitalValue] = useState(1000);
    5. const inputRef = useRef(null);
    6. 
    7. useEffect(() => {
    8.  console.log(capitalValue);
    9. }, [capitalValue]);
   10.
   11. const ChangeCapital = () => {
   12.   setcapitalValue(inputRef.current.value - 100);
   13. };
   14. 
   15. return (
   16.   <>
   17.     <button onClick={ChangeCapital}>click</button>
   18.     <input ref={inputRef} type="number" />
   19.   </>
   20.  );
   21. };
   22. 
   23. export default CompoundIntrest;
```

At line 5, we have created a ref with initial value `null` using [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook of react, which later will be used to store reference of `input` element.

At line 18, we have assigned the `inputRef` to the ref of `input` element, which will be use to get the value from the field.

At line 12, we are getting the value of `input` as `inputRef.current.value`  .

To check the update in the value of `capitalValue` state `onClick` event of `button` we can use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook of react ( From Line 7 to Line 9 is doing the same ).

**PS** : Please let me know if this clear your doubt or not. Thanks for reading the answer.

Answer (score -1):

your code is fine, and your state is successfuly updated, the problem is the timing of calling your console. react handles your code **async**, it means it starts your changeCapital, and before the change capital function is finished it calls the calculate function, so the value of your state, is the previous value.

you need to call your calculate function somewhere else:

1. you can call it in a [UseEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), this way your function gets called whenever your state has successfuly changed, or
2. you can call your calculate in 'onchange' event of your input feild

if you want the better solution, the first one is ***more reactly*** than the second one